# openssl 3.0.5 failing on rasperrypi 22.04

Tags: build, raspberry-pi, openssl

I have tried following build from source steps

```
curl -OJ https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.5.tar.gz
tar -xzf openssl-3.0.5.tar.gz
cd openssl-3.0.5
./config shared -Wl,-rpath=/opt/openssl/lib64 --prefix=/opt/openssl --openssldir=/opt/openssl/ssl
make -j 4
make install
cd ..
rm /usr/bin/openssl
ln -s /opt/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/*.* /opt/openssl/ssl/certs/
echo "/opt/openssl/lib64" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf
ldconfig
reboot
```

However during the `make` process I get the following error:

```
'-mfloat-abi=hard': selected processor lacks an FPU
```

I however believe that the rpi4 does in fact have one.
Am I mistaken or is there some other error?
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you can do to solve this is include the instruction set to which you are compiling openSSL

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [[ $1 != '' ]]
then
    echo "Getting openssl version ${1}"
    sudo apt -y install libcurl4-openssl-dev librtmp-dev curl
    curl -OJ "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-${1}.tar.gz"
    tar -xzf openssl-${1}.tar.gz
    cd openssl-${1}
    ./config shared -Wl,-rpath=/opt/openssl/lib --prefix=/opt/openssl --openssldir=/opt/openssl/ssl -march=armv7-a+fp
    make -j 4
    make install
    cd ..
    rm /usr/bin/openssl
    ln -s /opt/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
    ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/*.* /opt/openssl/ssl/certs/
    echo "/opt/openssl/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl.conf
    echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib" > /etc/profile.d/openssl.sh
    ldconfig
    rm openssl-${1}.tar.gz
    rm -rf openssl-${1}
    reboot
else
    echo Please provide latest openssl version \(3.x.x\) from:
    echo https://www.openssl.org/source/
fi
```

The above script when saved to a bash file. Eg. openssl.sh

Will take care of your problem. Remember to feed in the openssl version you are targeting.

```
./openssl.sh 3.0.7
```

**-march=armv7-a+fp** is only meant for hardware that supports 32 bit arm based instructions such as RaspberryPi's.

Hope this helps!